# 'sudo'- Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: sudo, segmentation-fault

I get *`"Segmentation fault (core dumped)"`* massage in output of any command in my shell with `sudo`. for example `sudo install any app` or `rm any file` and ...

Comment: Does `pkexec apt update` also tell you something about the segmentation fault?

Answer (score 0):

When you get a segmentation fault for all commands, the issue is generally one of two things:

1. Bad memory
   ⇢ Reboot and use `memtester` or `memtest86` to test your memory. You can find this in your Grub menu after booting.
2. A bad library that is used across multiple programs.
   ⇢ If you have recently upgraded, there is a possibility that the upgrade was interrupted before completing or some package is interfering with an important library.

Hope this points you in the right direction